# kotlin android pickerView

Tags: android, kotlin, pickerview

I am a beginner of Kotlin in Android and would like to create an pickerViewer (as below image) in Android Kotlin. 
[image]

I found https://github.com/Bigkoo/Android-PickerView on the web, but I don't know how to use it because the code is Java.
I am asking for the solution with source code. Please kindly help.

Comment: SO is for asking question, not "teaching you with source code" -- which I assume means that you're asking for the solution

Comment: @JamesZ yes, thank you! I will update the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

java

```
TimePickerView pvTime = new TimePickerBuilder( this, new OnTimeSelectListener() {
    @Override
   public void onTimeSelect(Date date, View v) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getTime(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } }).build();
```

kotlin

```
 val pvTime = TimePickerBuilder( this, {  date, v  ->
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getTime(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
   }  ).build()
```

you can first code in java, then use "Code> convert to Kotlin" in the android studio, so that you can compare between the two.

Comment: I would like to make a pickerview for country and city. Can you show me how to do it?